# What version of OpenSSH is included with macOS Catalina (10.15) beta?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, catalina

I'm interested to know which version of OpenSSH ships today on Catalina beta

Can someone running the beta version of Catalina run the following command in Terminal for me and provide the output?

```
/usr/bin/ssh -V
```

For macOS 10.14 the output is `OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`

So I'm after the output in macOS Catalina beta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not useful in the future - it is a beta so might not work and will not be useful in the future. And many who have the beta and the best knowledge  are not allowed to answer here. Ask on the Apple beta mailing lists

Comment: @mark No need to close beta, just put in a specific date in the text and answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lastest macOS Catalina Beta shows the identical version to the current Mojave `ssh`

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15
BuildVersion:   19A536g
$ /usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

Comment: 10.15 beta7 (19A546d) was released yesterday, confirming here it is still the same.